# Код ничего не выводит

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Код ничего не выводит, хотя должно по идее выводиться

```php
<?php
Class ShoppingCard{
    private $name;
    
    public function date(){
        $this -> $name = "PHP";
        echo $this-> $name;
    }
}
$product1=new ShoppingCard();
$product1.function date();
    ?>
```

Comment: А где вызов функции?

Comment: чего вдруг не выводит, parse error выводит от конструкции в последней строке.

Comment: Я так правильно вызываю функцию $product1.function date();?

Comment: очевидно, нет..

Comment: не могли бы ли Вы мне подсказать как правильно вызвать функцию ,просто в жаве так создаешь объект и можешь вызвать функцию а вот PHP я только сегодня начала учить

Comment: т.е. в яве вы тоже функции вызываете примерно как ``product1.public static date()``?

Comment: нет,product1.date();В жаве через точку вызывается метод

Comment: и я начала вызывать метод в PHP вот так :product1.date();но теперь я знаю что надо так $product1->date(); Немного не привычно )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP к свойствам и методам (name и date() в Вашем случае) знак доллар уже не пишется, еще у Вас не правильный вызов метода у объекта опять же не через точку как в js, а через стрелку. Попробуйте так

```
class ShoppingCard{
    private $name;

    public function date()
    {
        $this->name = "PHP";
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

$product1 = new ShoppingCard();
$product1->date();
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за помощь

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.properties.php вот на всякий случай, очень полезный ресурс))

Comment: Если честно ,я удивлена про скобки ,что скобка закрывает сначала класс а потом вызывается метод ,я думала что в  конце программы ставится скобка для закрытия класса

Answer (score 1):

У тебя там явно ошибка, код должен выглядит вот так

```
Class ShoppingCard{
   private $name;

   public function date(){
      $this->name = "PHP";
      echo $this->name;
   }
}
$product1 = new ShoppingCard();
$product1->date();
```

ты допустил три ошибки:

1. `$this->$name` - ты написал name с `$`, это неправильно нужно без `$` - $this->name
2. Ты вызываешь функцию через точку, и + пишешь `function` зачем?, ставить точку про привычке я панимаю ( это не пайтон ), но зачем писать `function`?, вызывать функцию надо вот так `$product1->date()`
3. Ты ставишь пробелы в $this: `$this -> name` - так не ставят